# Adding multiple tags in one result in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

## In the line when defining adress I want to add 4 results from different  tags into 1. But I cannot figure out how to do so.

```
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, openpyxl

#excel =  openpyxl.Workbook()
#print(excel.sheetnames)
#sheet = excel.active
#sheet.title = 'KNX manufacturers'
#print(excel.sheetnames)
#sheet.append(['name', 'description', 'country', 'website', 'phone', 'CEO', 'adress'])

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.knx.org/knx-en/for-professionals/community/manufacturers/')
    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

    companys = soup.find('div', class_="accordion").find_all('li')
    
    for company in companys:

        name = company.find('span', class_="desktop_only").text

        description = company.find('div', class_="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12").text.strip()

        country = company.find('div', class_="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 item").span.text

        website = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").a.text

        phone = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").find_all('span')[5].text.strip('Phone: ')

        CEO = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").find_all('strong')[0].text.strip()

        adress = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").find_all('span')[1, 2, 3, 4].text

        print(adress)
        #print(name, description, country, website, phone, CEO, adress)
        #sheet.append([name, description, country, website, phone, CEO, adress])
        break

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

#excel.save('KNX manufacturers | Bemsiq.xlsx')`
```

**I tried adding find_all('span')[1, 2, 3, 4] but it can only show one of these results at the time.**

Comment: `find_all` returns a list and you can create a list with the desired elements in the same way as for any usual Python list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all data from the table to pandas DataFrame you can try:

```py
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.knx.org/knx-en/for-professionals/community/manufacturers/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

def get_text(tag):
    return re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', tag.text.strip())

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('.accordion-body'):
    name = a.select_one('.mobile_only').text
    phone = a.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Phone:")')
    phone = phone.find_next_sibling(string=True) if phone else '-'

    web = a.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Website:") + a')
    web = web['href'] if web else '-'

    email = a.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Email:") + a')
    email = email['href'] if email else '-'

    person = a.strong
    line1 = person.find_next_sibling("span")
    line2 = line1.find_next_sibling("span")
    line3 = line2.find_next_sibling("span")

    address = f'{get_text(line1)}, {get_text(line2)}, {get_text(line3)}'
    person = person.text

    all_data.append((name, phone, web, email, person, address))


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Name', 'Phone', 'Web', 'Email', 'Person', 'Address'])
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Name | Phone | Web | Email | Person | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [mn]medianet | +49.6103697784 | https://www.medianet-home.de/ | info@medianet-home.de | Bernhard Hnida | Am Taubhaus 29, 63303 Dreieich, Germany |
| 1Home Solutions GmbH | +386.51300606 | http://www.1home.io | dejan.bukovnik@voxior.com | Dejan Bukovnik | Wattstrasse 11, 13355 Berlin, Germany |
| 3domotic Global Systems, S.L. | +34.610991993 | - | software@3atel.com | Santiago Ribas Roca | Enric Granados 153, Pral Bis - 1, 08008 Barcelona, Spain |
| 4ba GmbH | +49.6461980440 | http://www.4ba-gmbh.de | oh@dacom-homeautomation.de | Oliver Herrmann | Am Roten Stein 9A, 35216 Biedenkopf, Germany |
| ABB France | +33.561151845 | http://www.abb.com | cathy.zotti@fr.abb.com | Serge Le Men | rue Paul Gauguin 33, 31100 Toulouse, France |
| ABB LV Installation Materials Company Limited, Beijing | +86.1058085086 | http://www.abb.com.cn | yuwei.dai@cn.abb.com | Yuwei Dai | Kangding Street No. 17, 100176 Beijing, China |
| ABB S.p.A. | +39.35395269 | http://www.abb.com/it | marco.simonella@it.abb.com | Marco Simonella | Via delle Industrie 18, 20010 Vittuone, Italy |
| ABB Schweiz Ltd. | +41 58/5864566 | http://www.levyfils.ch | tudor.baiatu@ch.abb.com | Tudor Baiatu | Fulachstrasse 150, 8201 Schaffhausen, Switzerland |
| ABB Stotz-Kontakt GmbH | +49.62217011357 | http://www.abb.com/knx | volker.biewendt@de.abb.com | Volker Biewendt | Eppelheimer Straße 82, 69123 Heidelberg, Germany |
| ABB Xiamen Smart Technology Co., Ltd. | +86.5927616016 | https://new.abb.com/ | sylvia-shanshan.wang@cn.abb.com | Sylvia Wang | FangShanXiEr Road No.881, 361000 Xiamen, China |

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is that you cannot pass a list of indices directly inside find_all() as you attempted. Instead, you should use a list comprehension or separate find_all() calls to extract the results from different tags and then concatenate them into a single string.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.knx.org/knx-en/for-professionals/community/manufacturers/')
    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

    companys = soup.find('div', class_="accordion").find_all('li')
    
    for company in companys:

        name = company.find('span', class_="desktop_only").text
        description = company.find('div', class_="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12").text.strip()
        country = company.find('div', class_="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 item").span.text
        website = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").a.text
        phone = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").find_all('span')[5].text.strip('Phone: ')
        CEO = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").find_all('strong')[0].text.strip()

        # Extract the address components separately
        address_parts = company.find('div', class_="col-sm-6 col-xs-12").find_all('span')[1:5]
        address = ', '.join(part.text for part in address_parts)

        print(address)
        # Do further processing or saving to Excel
        break

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

With this modification, the address components (span elements 1 to 4) are extracted separately and then joined together with a comma using ', '.join(), creating a single address string containing all the address parts.

Now you should see the complete address printed for each company, and you can proceed with further processing or saving to an Excel file as desired.